# Windows mobile controlling scroll bar with finger

Tags: windows, compact-framework, mobile, pocketpc

I have a question about the windows mobile development. 
I created a mobile form on the windows mobile 6.0 test project. But that example form slightly larger than the vertically normal pocketpc forms. I now everybody said you can press the scrollbar for accessing bottom or any location of the form.

But i need to use the finger for easy navigating form areas. This kind of iphone :) 
Is it possible ? how can i make this ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile 6.5 adds gesture support, that is supposed to allow such functionality for finger control.  Of course, your code has to take advantage of it.

You can also write your own, which isn't difficult, but still cumbersome.

Comment: Sebastian thank you for your advise, i have searhed for 3 days. It seems you are right. We have to wait wm 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

My answer could be classified as subjective.  I try to now show the scroll bar when possible for just that reason.  On most devices that have touch screen, you can scroll using you finger (and I'm a somewhat large guy -- 6'3" with farmer kid hands).

But if you are displaying a grid, that isn't always possible.  The results can go off the screen very easily.  Oh well, grab a pen and hit the scrollbar.

Other screen elements that can help: tab control.  separate your controls into groups and put each group on a separate tab.  I also do a lot of wizards with LARGE next and previous buttons.

But in all of this, if it is designed to be stylus free, just pray the user doesn't have to type anything using the screen soft keyboard.  That just doesn't work with a finger.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your know-how, it will be help for me.